# Proof for exponentiation in modular arithemetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I have found out, that the following is true for modular arithmetic when $t$ is a natural number.

$$a^t \bmod\ n \equiv (a\bmod\ n)^t\bmod\ n$$

But I have been unable to find a proof for this, does anyone have a source that proves this conjecture?

Comment: **Hint** $$(a+cn)(b+dn)-ab=n(ad+bc+cdn).$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$a^t-b^t=(a-b)(a^{t-1}+a^{t-2}b+\cdots+ab^{t-2}+b^{t-1})$$

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. $$(a^{t−1}+a^{t−2}b+⋯+ab^{t−2}+b^{t−1})$$what pattern does it follow, ie. what is the "..."?

Comment: From the given equality if $n$ divides $a-b$ it divides also $a^t-b^t$. Right?

Comment: Yes, I'm with you on that.

Comment: So what's the meaning of $a\equiv b (mod \;n)$?

Comment: That's $$a\ mod\ n\ =\ b$$ right?

Comment: Yes but also means $n$ divides $a-b$.

Comment: But, how is that relevent for what we are trying to prove, there is no substraction?

Comment: Looks like they left you hanging.

Answer (score 0):

We want to prove $$a^t \bmod\ n \equiv (a\bmod\ n)^t\bmod\ n.$$
Let $ a \bmod n \equiv b $.

Thus by substitution we are proving $$a^t \bmod\ n \equiv b ^t\bmod\ n.$$
But this means we need to show $ n \mid a^t - b^t $ under the assumption that $ n \mid a - b $ .

Then using the fact that $a^t-b^t=(a-b)(a^{t-1}+a^{t-2}b+\cdots+ab^{t-2}+b^{t-1})$